# Query with Joins and string concatenation

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I am new to C# and am coming from VB6.  Can anyone see why this query may not work in C#?

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT " +
                      "S.idGroup, S.idStatement, P1.nameLast " +
                      "FROM " +
                      "STATEMENTS S, " +
                      "GROUPS G, " +
                      "PEOPLE P1, " +
                      "S LEFT JOIN G on G.id = S.idGroup, " +
                      "G LEFT JOIN P1 on P1.id = G.idContactPerson " +
                      "WHERE " +
                      "S.idTrip = @idTrip";
```

Comment: what is the error? how do you now this is not working?

Comment: What error message do you get, if any? Or, more generally: What happens, and what is supposed to happen?

Comment: With this piece of code? No!

Comment: Sorry, it mysteriously works now!

Comment: You really shouldn't be doing all that string concatenation, just use a string literal. Aside from that, this really doesn't have anything to do with C#.

Answer (score 1):

I think your SQL syntax is incorrect, try this one

```
"SELECT S.idGroup, S.idStatement, P1.nameLast " +
"FROM STATEMENTS S LEFT JOIN GROUPS G on G.id = S.idGroup " +
"LEFT JOIN People P1 on P1.id = G.idContactPerson " +
"WHERE S.idTrip = @idTrip";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Command.CommandText = @"SELECT S.idGroup, S.idStatement, P1.nameLast 
                      FROM STATEMENTS S LEFT JOIN GROUPS G on G.id = S.idGroup 
                      LEFT JOIN People P1 on P1.id = G.idContactPerson 
                      WHERE S.idTrip = " @idTrip;
```

Try this syntax!

Answer (score 0):

if you MUST build your SQL in this fashion, use the StringBuilder class to build up the command string.